# applying standard regression techniques to time series prediction via second level forcasting

Tags: regression, time-series, sas

The author of the book:

[Practical Time Series Forecasting with R: A Hands-On Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Time-Forecasting-Hands-Analytics-ebook/dp/B01IPLASG6)

suggests fitting a second level forecasting model to the residuals of a standard (first level) regression model in order to deal with auto regression via standard regression methods (auto regression violates one of standard regression's assumption). I have to admit that I do not fully understand this. Did anyone follow such a methodology to be able to use standard regression packages (e.g. PROC GLMSELECT in SAS)? Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could use proc arima or proc autoreg in SAS as these are time series procedures that would be able to handle auto correlated errors.

Comment: I know but don't have ets!